# Explain this dig command

Tags: dns, dig

Please explain what this command will do and whether it can be undone:

```
dig +nocmd strongimages.tld mx +noall +answer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call to the [`dig`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) command command lists the [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) for `strongimages.tld`. The choice of display options suppress extra commentary from `dig`, you just get the lines with the records.

You can undo the displaying of these lines by clearing the screen. If any server on the way logged or cached your request, you can't undo that unless you have administrative access to that server.

This command doesn't change any configuration anywhere, if that's what you were worried about.